# Test modal dialog with Qt Test

Tags: unit-testing, qt, modal-dialog

I am trying to write a unit test for a GUI application using the QTestLib. The problem is that one of the slots creates a modal dialog using `exec()`  and I found no possibility to interact with the dialog.

The slots which creates the dialog is connected to a QAction. So the first problem is that the test blocks when I trigger the QAction in the test since this results in the call to `exec()`. Therefore, I tried creating a QThread that performs the interaction. However, this did not help.

Things I already tried (all performed from within the "interaction helper" thread):

1. Send key clicks using `QTest::keyClicks()`

   - Results in error message "QCoreApplication::sendEvent(): Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread"
2. Post QKeyEvents using `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`

   - <strike>Doesn't work, i.e. nothing happens. I guess because the events end up in the event loop of the thread that owns the dialog, which will not be reached until the dialog is closed and `exec()` returns.</strike> *See Edit below*
3. Invoking Slots on the dialog using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`

   - <strike>Doesn't work, i.e. nothing happens. I guess for the same reason as `postEvent()` doesn't work.</strike> *See Edit below*

So the question is: Is there any way to interact programmatically with a modal dialog that was opened using the `exec()` method?

**Edit:** Actually, method 3 is working. The problem was a different one:
I passed the arguments to `invokeMethod()` to the "interaction helper" thread and for some reason, accessing the arguments did not work from that thread (I got no SEG errors but they were simply empty).
I guess that method 2 is also working and I simply had the same problem as with method 3 but I didn't test that.

Comment: To prevent comments: I know that I could also create the dialog using `setModal(true)` and `show()` and handle the return value asynchronously. But my question is aimed at `exec()` explicitly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution I use in command line applications which use Qt libraries meant for GUIs is the `singleShot`, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9521335/594137) alludes. In those cases it looks like this:

```
QCoreApplication app(argc, argv);

// ...

QTimer::singleShot(0, &app, SLOT(quit()));
return app.exec();
```

So in your case I imagine it would look something like this:

```
QDialog * p_modalDialog = getThePointer(); // you will have to replace this with
                                           // a real way of getting the pointer

QTimer::singleShot(0, p_modalDialog, SLOT(accept()));

p_modalDialog->exec(); // called somewhere else in your case
                       // but it will be automatically accepted.
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but in my test I need to pass 1 as the first argument to `QTimer::singleShot`, otherwise the slot is never called (and the dialog shows up and waits patiently until I click OK). Thats with "QTest library 4.8.1, Qt 4.8.1" on Mac OSX 10.6.

Answer (score 5):

You can keep the interaction in the same thread by delaying its execution until the dialog event loop starts.

For example just before the `exec()` call, you use either `QTimer::singleShot` with 0 as interval or `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` with connection type `Qt::QueuedConnection` to invoke the slot that needs to be executed while the dialog is shown.

Comment: This answer is correct as well. However, I accepted the other answer because it was more detailed.

Answer (score 3):

You can also post the events before calling `exec()`.
As soon as the dialog has been constructed after the `exec()` call, the events will be executed.

For example to test an Esc key press (means reject/close the dialog):

```
// create a dialog
QDialog d = ...
//post an Escape key press and release event
QApplication::postEvent(&d, new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress  , Qt::Key_Escape, Qt::NoModifier) );
QApplication::postEvent(&d, new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyRelease, Qt::Key_Escape, Qt::NoModifier) );
// execute and check result
int ret = d.exec();
QCOMPARE(ret, static_cast<int>(QDialog::Rejected));
```

Answer (score 0):

related question's answer has some extra details about flushing the event queue during a test:
[Qt event loop and unit testing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606125/qt-event-loop-and-unit-testing/22951970#22951970)