# Functional Test for QMessageBox... why does not work?

Tags: python, pyqt, tdd, pyside, qttest

I would develop some functional tests for a pyqt application that uses PyQt (or PySide) as GUI library. The tests use Unittest and Qttest library, as reported in many resources, for example this stackoverflow question: [Unit and functional testing a PySide-based application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145583/unit-and-functional-testing-a-pyside-based-application) 
For the main window all works fine, and the code simulate perfectly Keyboard Types and Mouse Clicks and Movements, but the "*devil is in the details*"... and this method does not work for a QMessageBox.

In the class of the Main Window, for manage a `IOError` on opening a file, I initialize a QMessageBox:

```
self.IOErrMsgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox()
self.IOErrMsgBox.setText("<b>Error</b>")
self.IOErrMsgBox.setInformativeText("""
                                    <p>There was an error opening
                                    the project file:
                                    %s.</p>"""%(path,))
self.IOErrMsgBox.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
self.IOErrMsgBox.setDefaultButton(QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
self.IOErrMsgBox.exec_()
```

To test how it works, in functional test I have:

```
def test__open_project(self):
    self.MainWin._project_open(wrong_path, flag='c') 
    # the function that handles the exception 
    # and initializes the QMessageBox.
    IOErrMsgBox = self.MainWin.IOErrMsgBox
    # Reference to the initialized QMessageBox.
    self.assertIsInstance(IOErrMsgBox, QMessageBox)
    okWidget = self.MainWin.IOErrMsgBox.button(IOErrMsgBox.Ok)
    QTest.mouseClick(okWidget, Qt.LeftButton)
```

or, in altenative:

```
def test__open_project(self):
     #... some code, exactly like previous example except for last row...
     QTest.keyClick(okWidget, 'o', Qt.AltModifier)
```

but No one works... and the Ok button is not clicked and I can do it with my mouse pointer :(

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is in general about how to test **modal dialogs**.

Any modal dialog including QMessageBox will not return from `exec_()` until it is closed, so the test code in your second code box probably never gets executed.

You could just `show()` it (making it non-modal) and then follow your code but don't forget to close and delete the dialog afterwards.

Or you use a Timer and schedule a click on the OK button (similar to [Test modal dialog with Qt Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518484/test-modal-dialog-with-qt-test)). Here is an example:

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

app = QtGui.QApplication([])

box = QtGui.QMessageBox()
box.setStandardButtons(QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
button = box.button(QtGui.QMessageBox.Ok)
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, button.clicked)
box.exec_()
```