# QT close window by QTest in locked thread

Tags: c++, qt, qtestlib

I have a QT application and I want to test it with QTest. Shortly about what I wanna do: I have a Main Window, where the button **Settings** is located. If I click on this button, the QDialog is appeared. I want to test if this really happens

```
MainWindow mwindow;
QTest::mouseClick(mwindow->showButton, QtCore::Qt::LeftButton)
```

and then I would check for presence of text in new dialog and so on.

The dialog appears but - how do I close it within the test without closing it manually? And how do I test for text presence in it. If I got it right, I can't do anything in test while the dialog is shown.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `QTimer` and [QTest::keyClick()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#keyClick).

If your `QMessgeBox`'s pointer is `msgBox`, in `QTimer`'s `timeout()` slot,

```
QTest::keyClick( msgBox, Qt::Key_Enter);
```

Also, You can test for text with [QCOMPARE macro](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtest.html#QCOMPARE).

```
QCOMPARE( sourceText, targetText );
```

**APPEND**

I think [QTimer::singleShot](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot) is a useful for solving your question.

```
QMessageBox test;
QDialog& dlg = test;
QTimer::singleShot( 2000, &dlg, SLOT( close() ) );
dlg.exec();
```

In above code, test messagebox will close after 2 seconds.
So, your code maybe..

```
MainWindow mwindow;
QDialog& dlg = mwindow;
QTimer::singleShot( 2000, &dlg, SLOT( close() ) ); //or SLOT( quit() )?
QTest::mouseClick(mwindow->showButton, QtCore::Qt::LeftButton)
```

however, I've not tested.
Also, try to read [this articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518484/test-modal-dialog-with-qt-test).
I hope this can help you.

Comment: If I don't have a pointer yet (say, It'll be created when the button is pressed) - I can't use your solution, right?